# IntelliJ terminal messed up prints duplicate message (instead of updating)

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Recently got a new computer with "IntelliJ 2021.1.3 CE" installed, but somehow the terminal console is printing redundant message instead of "updating" messages.
I have pointed my Terminal's Shellpath to "E:\git\bin\bash.exe", but if run the same build command with gitbash.exe, I don't run into below issues...
Thanks in advance for any helps/suggestion !!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using (*Help | About*)?

Comment: tks, updated my question with versino "IntelliJ 2021.1.3 CE"